# javascript: Why does this return statement cause a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, aptana3

I'm using Apatana 3, i modified the JS code formatter a little bit to let it seem more clear, below is the code after format, it give me an error:

```
    copyOffset : function( index )
    {
        return
        {
            x : index, y : index
        };
    }
```

firebug give me:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

if i change it to:

```
    copyOffset : function( index )
    {
        return{
            x : index, y : index
        };
    }
```

will be OK, Anybody who can tell me what's the diff between these two return statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the first snippet is actually interpreted as...

```
copyOffset : function( index )
{
    return;
    {
        x : index, y : index
    };
}
```

It's called [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons): when JavaScript parser sees a statement that seems to be complete, but misses semicolon, it attempts to 'fix' it.

And yes, even though helpful at times, it can be quite annoying. [This article](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) explains this JavaScript feature in details.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i'm from java and i like a new line when starting a block, i guess i have to go back to change my formatting. JS is somewhat unexpected i think.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, this is a classical one;)

Javasript breaks on

```
return
{
```

because it treats `{` as a new block and implicitely inserts a semicolon:

```
return;
{
```

thus returning undefined:-D

The Problem is Javasript inserting a Semicolon at the end of a line when the statement makes sense. Since `return` can stand on it's own, Javascript interprets it as a complete statement and inserts the semicolon, thus breaking your code.

Actually, this is the reason, why in Javascript you alway should avoid those newlines and write:

```
copyOffset : function( index ){
    return{
        x : index, y : index
    };
}
```